# No module named resource (installing Flask-Mail)

Tags: python, virtualenv, flask

A little new to python and the wonderful world of Flask.

I'm trying to install Flask-Mail (http://packages.python.org/flask-mail/) and coming up against a bit of a wall.

Using a virutalenv (on WINDOWS7) I can't get the flask-mail to install, each time I recieve 'No module named resource'.

I'm using pip to install... any ideas?

Comment: Sorry i've since moved to a linux system to solve the problem (linux was the production box anyway. it was development that had this issue). To re-produce (on windows): 1. install virtualenv 2.make an env 3. install flask to that env 4. try and easy_install flask-mail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Flask-Mail documentation says:

> Flask-Mail requires the use of the Lamson library, which unfortunately has dependencies that do not work on Windows.
>
> You can install Flask-Mail, Lamson and other libraries with the no dependencies option:
>
> ```
> easy_install -N lamson chardet Flask-Mail
> ```

Source: http://packages.python.org/Flask-Mail/#windows-issues

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error, too. And I searched Python index found this: http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html , It seems that resource is platform-dependent module, and to be specific, on Unix. And also this:
http://code.activestate.com/pypm/lamson/ (can not insert image here? suck!) lamson is not built on any version(32 or 64-bit) of Windows(suck, too).